# Find the square of a 3x3 matrix that equals the negative Identity3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There are $2\times2$ matrices $A$ such that $A^2 = -I_2$. 
For example, if 
$$
A = \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
0& -1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

then $A^2 = -I_2 = \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
-1& 0\\
0 &-1\\
\end{array} \right ]$.

Is there a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = -I_3$? If so, find such an $A$. If not, show no such $A$ exists. (hint: use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are $n \times n$ matrices then $|XY| = |X|*|Y|$.

Please help or give some pointers. I've spent hours on this and I can't seem to figure out out! Thanks!

Comment: What have you been trying (other than 'spending hours')?  What tools do you believe you have at your disposal?

Comment: Here's one very big and straightforward hint: if $A^2=-I_3$, what is $\det(A)$?

Comment: This depends on the field. E.g. if $A$ is complex, there is an obvious solution.

Comment: Not complex. Steven... I'm helping someone else do the problem and haven't done matrix math in years. My Ti-89 is nowhere to be found and I've got nothing but google. If I had a textbook I would read it. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if $A^2=-I$, then $\det(A^2)=\det(-I)$. Or $(\det(A))^2=-1$ meaning that the entries MUST be complex. Two examples that work are $iI$ and $-iI$. Squaring both gives $-I$.

Comment: So in terms of real answers, there is no solution? I guess this works for the 2x2 matrix since the determinant is positive, right?

Comment: You can find real matrices when $n$ is even and you need complex when $n$ is odd. Although you shouldn't be afraid of complex numbers.